# AngularJS : mock http service (Using $httpBackend) to respond with some data to the success method of Promise API

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-mock, angular-promise

I tried to interpret simpler version of my question.
1)I m writing Unit tests forcontroller(myController) method(subtract).
2)mocking http using httpbackend i want to return a response of 200 to success function of http in subtract method to down its value in the success function of any dummy DELETE url(which is always successful outside test environment).
3)But i see expect(scope.testvalue) to be 5 only.
 Any help is appreciated.

```
'use strict';
describe('MyController UNIT TEST specs ', function () {    
var scope, http, location, ctrl, httpBackend;
beforeEach(module('myApp', 'ui.router')); 

beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $http, $controller, $httpBackend) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    http = $http;
    httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    ctrl = $controller('myController', { $scope: scope, $http: http});
    httpBackend.when('DELETE', 'url').respond(200, 'fsdf');
}));

afterEach(function () {
    httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
});    

it('test 1 : Subtract 1 from a value enter code here` using subtract method in myController', function () {
    httpBackend.when('DELETE', 'url').respond(200);
    var testvalue = 5;
    scope.subtract(testvalue);
    expect(testvalue).toBe(4);
});
});
angular.module("myApp").controller("myController", function ($scope, $http) {    
    $scope.subtract = function (testValue) {    
        $http({
            method: 'DELETE',
            url: 'url'
        }).then(function (data) { //success    
            //irrespective of data subtract 1 here     
            testValue - 1 = 4;    
        }, function (errResult) { //fail
            console.log(errResult);
        });
    }
})
```

Error i see is (expected)
**Error: Expected false to be true.**

Answer (score 3):

In unit testing using angular-mock, you have to call `httpBackend.flush()` manually to start simulating the http request/response before expecting the result like this:

```
it('test 1 : Subtract 1 from a value enter code here` using subtract method in myController', function () {
    httpBackend.when('DELETE', 'url').respond(200);
    var testObj = { testValue: 5 };
    scope.subtract(testObj);
    httpBackend.flush();
    expect(testObj.testValue).toBe(4);
});
```

And your http callback doesn't modify the `scope.testvalue`, if you are expecting the `testvalue` in `scope` to changed the callback should be like this:

```
$scope.subtract = function (testObj) {
    $http({
        method: 'DELETE',
        url: 'url'
    }).then(function (data) { //success
        //irrespective of data subtract 1 here
        testObj.testValue = testObj.testValue - 1;
    }, function (errResult) { //fail
        console.log(errResult);
    });
};
```

For the full working example see: http://plnkr.co/edit/kFt5vV8zCtZpfJvduujc?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.Sorry I had to edit the code.
1)The error seems to be Error: No pending request to flush ! when the flush is called on httpBackend.
1)Sry its not scope test value, I'm passing as argument but the variable itself.

Comment: Where exactly did you put the httpBackend.flush() call?

Comment: after line "scope.subtract(testvalue);" inside test

Comment: I've updated the answer and included the plunker example. Please see if that is what you want. Also in javascript, argument variables are pass by value, so if you want to modify the variable in-place, you have to, at least, wrap it inside an object like in the answer.

Comment: Can you tell me one thing. while running the test is it entering success function?
In my case It's not entering the success method to be able to manipulate testObj

Comment: Yes, the success function is called. May be you could try debugging the plunker with devtools and compare with your code to see what is the difference.